# Locally opening a transformers saved model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have a saved transformers model using `BertModel.from_pretrained('test_model')`

I have trained this model using google colab's GPUs

Then, I want to open it, with `BertModel.from_pretrained('test_model/')`
but I do not  have a GPU in my local PC. I get this:

```
/home/seiji/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

What shoud I do? I have no idea of how can I open it using a CPU. And is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

The best thing you can do is save the CPU version of the model, i.e:

```py
model.cpu().save_pretrained("model_directory")
```

All the pre-trained Huggingface models are saved as CPU models anyway and you always need to move them to GPU explicitly.

PyTorch allows loading GPU models on CPU (see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/on-a-cpu-device-how-to-load-checkpoint-saved-on-gpu-device/349), but the arguments of `torch.load` you would need to set are not exposed via the API, so you would need write your own `from_pretrained` method.